# Nethunter terminal opening

Tags: kali-linux

[image]
First how I run this tools in my terminal like run a Kali nethunter or how I remove this all 
I already install tools in my terminal but I don't how I individuals run a tool in termux like I already install trape in turmax but I don't how I run this in my turmax and how I actually open in my turmax terminal

Comment: I don’t understand what your question is. Could you edit it to be more clear?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Kali Linux so hard to set up? Why won't people help me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me)

Comment: To answer your first question: You can start Kali-Nethunter by entering `./kalinethunter`.

Answer (score 2):

In your image we see Termux. A terminal emulator for android. With this app you can run a bunch of linux commands even without root (depending what you want to do). 
On the other hand, Kali Nethunter is custom Android ROM that is available for some Nexus models and OnePlus One. If you have one of this smartphone models you can install Nethunter on it, if not, you can use Termux pkg that is similar to APT from Debian based linux distros, and then search for a list of tools that are available on Termux repositories that you may find useful based on Nethunter tools.

PS: If you have a .deb package of the software you want to use, Termux also accept the command dpkg for installation: `dpkg -i ./package.deb`